# Printing sum of digits greater than average

Tags: c, sum, average, variable-assignment

For an assignment, I have to write a code **in C** that prints the digits from a number that are greater than its average.

I already wrote some code, but when I insert a single number or a number with the same digits (like 555), it does not give me an answer. It  should give, in the case of 555 --> 5 (and 8 -> 8, 77 -> etc.)

The code I wrote is:

(I've commented at every step I take.)

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, char *v[])  {
    /* imput: 1 number between 1 and 2.000.000.000 */
    int n;          /*  stores the value                            */
    int ext, ext2;  /*  stores a copy of the number                 */
    int rem;        /*  stores the remainders                       */
    int tot;        /*  stores the total of the digits              */
    int avg;        /*  stores the average of the digits            */
    int i;          /*  counts the amount of digits                 */
    int big;        /*  stores the biggest and second biggest value */

    scanf("%d", &n);

    /* seperate digits and add them */
    ext=n;
    ext2=n;
    tot=0;
    big=0;
    avg=0;
    i=0;

    while(ext!=0 && n<2000000000 && n>=1){
        rem=ext%10;
        tot=tot+rem;
        ext=ext/10;
        i++;
    };  

    /* average value */
    avg=tot/i;      

    /* find and print higher numbers */
    while (ext2>0){
        rem = ext2 % 10;
        if (rem > avg){
            big += rem;
        };
        ext2 = ext2 / 10;
    }

    if(n<100 && n>9){
        printf("%d\n", big);
    } else if(big==avg){
        printf("%d\n", 0);
    } else if(big>=avg){
        printf("%d\n", big);
    };

    return 0;
}
```

Hope someone can help me!

Comment: You're probably going to get a few downvotes because it looks like a homework dump the way it is formatted.  Try to condense it down to a specific question.  You've got a good start with the test case that doesn't work.

Comment: I would read the input with `fgets` and there you have the (ASCII) digits in a nice array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to failing to initialize `i = 0;` prior to `i++;`, your biggest problem is you are confusing yourself with the large number of unnecessary and nondescript variable names. `ext, ext2, tot, big, big2, avg, rem, rem2` is just variable salad.

While you will need `ext2` to hold a copy of the variable you reduce by `%` (modulo) to find `tot` and `avg`, there is no need for `rem2` or `big2` (you can simply reuse `rem`) and you only need one `big` (presuming that is your variable holding the sum of digits greater than `avg`)

Further, your loop to find `big` (and using `big2`) is wildly more confusing than it need be. You don't care if `rem2` is greater than `big2` and then setting `big2 = rem2;` what you care about is whether the digit is larger than `avg`. (that's it) All you need is:

```
    /* find and print higher numbers */
    while (ext2>0){
        rem = ext2 % 10;
        if (rem > avg){
            big += rem;
        };
        ext2 = ext2 / 10;
    }
```

Now `big` holds the sum of digits larger than averages.

Reusing variables and using descriptive variable names will go a long way to keeping your logic straight and prevent unnecessary variable sprawl. There is a normal rule-of-thumb to keep in mind when writing functions (it is good to keep in mind always), but if you are writing a function and you find yourself using more than 4-variables, you may need to refactor your program. (it's not a hard rule, but the crux of it is to prevent exactly the variable salad you fell into)

Why `long tot;`? At the very most `1+9+9+9+9+9+9+9+9+9 = 82`. The use of `int` like you use for the rest of your variables is fine. (given your constraint that `1≤n<2000000000`)

Lastly, while you can take the input numerically as you have and use modulo to extract each digit, it would be far simpler just to read the input as a string and then simply iterate over each character subtracting `'0'` to get the numeric value (as suggested in the comments by Weather Vane)

**Edit Tidying Up Variables**

From our continued discussion, I've decided to drop a quick edit that tidies the rest of the code up a bit and reduces the number of variables, as well as initializing the variables when they are declared. You could do something similar to:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)  {

    int n,          /*  stores the value                                */
        tmp,        /*  stores a copy of the number                     */
        rem,        /*  stores the remainders                           */
        tot = 0,    /*  stores the total of the digits                  */
        avg = 0,    /*  stores the average of the digits                */
        digits = 0, /*  counts the number of digits                     */
        big = 0;    /*  stores the sum of digits larger than avg        */

    /* imput: 1 number (1 <= n && n <= 2.000.000.000    */
    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1) { /* read/validate number */
        fputs ("error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    if (n < 1 || 2000000000 < n) {  /* validate n in allowable range */
        fputs ("error: input outside allowable value.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }

    tmp = n;
    while (tmp) {           /* sum digits for average */
        rem = tmp % 10;
        tot += rem;
        tmp /= 10;
        digits++;
    }
    avg = tot / digits;     /* calculate average */

    tmp = n;
    while (tmp) {           /* sum numbers higher than avg */
        rem = tmp % 10;
        if (rem > avg)
            big += rem;
        tmp /= 10;
    }

    printf ("sum of digits greater than avg : %d\n", big);
}
```

Nothing fancy, but `989 -> 18`, and `777 -> 0` and `778 -> 8`. Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: I'll take a look. Those will likely need special cases. Single digit, average is the digit so nothing to add. Example `5`, `avg = 5/1`, then sum of digits greater then `5` -- no digits are greater than `5`. Like I said, let me look and I'll drop another comment or edit my answer.

Comment: @BramKoop Why do you say with `777` outcome should be `7`? With `7+7+7 = 21` the average is then `21 / 3 = 7` -- there are no numbers higher than `avg` to sum. Are you saying you have another special condition if all number are equal then even though there are no digits greater than average, output a single digit when multiple digits are all the same??

Comment: Oops, I did not mean 7. Dumb... It should indeed be 0, because there are no digits greater than the average. You are right.

Comment: Okay, I can take out the extra variables then... It would be a nutty requirement, but then assignments are full of nutty requirements `:)`

Comment: Haha. True. I’ll try to delete and rename some variables and write a line that sets the outcome for 777 to 0. Thanks so far!

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to initialize variable `i` with 0. I've corrected your code and it gives expected outcome. And the answer is 0 for a single number because the average of one number is always the number itself so the number is never greater than the average.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()
{
    /* imput: 1 number between 1 and 2.000.000.000 */
    int n;          /*  stores the value                            */
    int ext, ext2;  /*  stores a copy of the number                 */
    int rem, rem2;  /*  stores the remainders                       */
    long tot;       /*  stores the total of the digits              */
    int avg;        /*  stores the average of the digits            */
    int i;          /*  counts the amount of digits                 */
    int big, big2;  /*  stores the biggest and second biggest value */
    int sum;        /*  stores sum of digits greater than average   */
    scanf("%d", &n);

    /* seperate digits and add them */
    ext=n;
    ext2=n;
    tot=0;
    big=0;
    big2=0;
    avg=0;
    i=0;
    sum=0;

    while(ext!=0 && n<2000000000 && n>=1)
    {
        rem=ext%10;
        tot=tot+rem;
        ext=ext/10;
        i++;
    };

    /* average value */
    avg=tot/i;

    /* find and print higher numbers */

    while(ext2>0)
    {
        rem2=ext2%10;
        if(rem2>avg)
        {
            sum+=rem2;
        };
        ext2=ext2/10;
    };

    printf("sum of digits greater than average: %d",sum);

    return 0;
}
```